# Select specific JSON key's value to sum it

Tags: javascript, json, sum, d3.js, key-value

For a JSON object that looks like this:

```
[{
    "gemeente": "amsterdam",
    "stadsdeel": "centrum",
    "adres": "damrak 28-30",
    "bvo": "2000",
},
{
    "gemeente": "amsterdam",
    "stadsdeel": "centrum",
    "adres": "damrak 66",
    "bvo": "1500",
    "": ""
}]
```

I'm trying to get a total sum of the `bvo` value. the output would in this case be 3500. Then I need to use this number for a data visualisation. I'm working whith `d3.js` but any Javascript solution would do.

Comment: In the future, either post your answer or delete the question. Marking it as [solved] doesn't help anybody. :)

Comment: You can also answer your question now.

Comment: You are right, i will try to answer my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 handles this quite well with [d3.sum](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_sum), without proper testing I think the syntax should be something like

```
d3.sum(list, function(d) { return d.bvo; });
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to parse the attribute before returning it: `return parseInt(d.bvo, 10);`.

Comment: d3.sum handles the parsing https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/arrays/sum.js basically it does `+d.bvo` to cast it to a integer

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
var list = [{
    "gemeente": "amsterdam",
    "stadsdeel": "centrum",
    "adres": "damrak 28-30",
    "bvo": "2000",
},
{
    "gemeente": "amsterdam",
    "stadsdeel": "centrum",
    "adres": "damrak 66",
    "bvo": "1500",
    "": ""
}];

// code to sum the values
var sum = 0;
for(var len = list.length, i=0; i < len; i++){ // for each object in the list
    var item = list[i]; 
    sum += parseInt(item.bvo, 10); // parse its "bvo" element as integer and add it to the sum
}

// output to console the sum.. or do whatever you want with the sum here..
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer with regular Javascript:

```
var SumByTipe = {};
for (i in data) {
    var currtipe = data[i].tipe;
    if (currtipe in SumByTipe) {
        for (j in data[i]) {
            if (j != "tipe" && j != "mc") {
                SumByTipe[currtipe][j + '_total'] += parseFloat(data[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        var firstSum = {};
        for (j in data[i]) {
            if (j != "tipe" && j != "mc"){
                firstSum[j + '_total'] = parseFloat(data[i][j]);
            }
        }
        SumByTipe[currtipe] = firstSum;
    }
}
console.log(SumByTipe);
```

Though I don't really get *how* it works, it worked fine. :-)